# Apex differentiate between RichTextArea, LongTextArea and TextArea

Tags: apex, fields, data-types, sobjecttype

When calling `getDescribe()` on a custom field I get the field data.

Although, I need to know when the field is `Text Area (Long)`, `Text Area (Rich)` or just `TextArea`.

When seeing the result from salesforce all of them have the same type `TextArea` without difference between each other.

Is that how it should work?

Is there a way I can differ between those three field types?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like theres 3 methods you can use to check the definition of a textarea:

1. `field.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.TEXTAREA`
2. `field.isHtmlFormatted()`
3. `field.getLength()`

Here's a snippet of these methods in use:

```
if (field.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.TEXTAREA) {
    if (field.getLength() <= 255 && !field.isHtmlFormatted()) {
        return 'TextArea';
    } else if ((field.getLength() >= 256 && field.getLength() <= 131072) && !field.isHtmlFormatted()) {
        return 'TextArea (Long)';
    } else if ((field.getLength() >= 256 && field.getLength() <= 131072) && field.isHtmlFormatted()) {
        return 'TextArea (Rich)';
    }
}
```